# how do I present a filtered dashboard table in qlik sense?

Tags: dashboard, qliksense

I built a dashboard in qlik sense and I am showing a table with clients and their orders from the beginning of the year until the end of the last month. that same table is a basis (DATA BASE) for all of my other computations in the dashboard.
I want that specific table to output only order which have not been completed.
How do I filter a table within the dashboard - NOT using the filter tab in the column header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the object data by using [Set Analysis](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/May2021/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm). This way the object's data is filtered no matter what are the applied filters (on the field(s) in the set analysis)

If the measure is:
`sum( {< OrderStatus = {'Completed'} >} Sales)`

Then the dimensions will be filtered to show only values for which `OrderStatus` is `Completed`. And even if you select `OrderStatus = NotCompleted` (or there are no selections in `OrderStatus` field) then the table will still show only the `Completed` values

**Update:**

If the table shows only dimensions (without any aggregation) then you can "convert" the client dimension to measure and use set analysis there:

`Only({< OrderStatus = {'Completed'} >} Client)`

And keep the other column(s) as dimensions.

The `Client` column is now a measure with the following expression:

[image: Expression]

And you can see the difference between the tables (added `OrderStatus` column just for the test):

[image: Result tables]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my table does not include aggregate values, thus I cannot use set analysis...

Answer (score 0):

If your table isn't otherwise using any measures, you can still use Set Analysis by using the `Aggr()` function as one of the dimensions:
`=Aggr(Only({<[Order Status] = {'Completed'}>} [Client]), [Client])`

You can see a few Qlik Community posts about that method [here](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-App-Dev/SET-ANALYSIS-ONLY-FOR-SELECTED-DIMENSION/m-p/1068673/highlight/true#M357106) and [here](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-App-Dev/Calculated-Dimension-using-ONLY-function/m-p/48620/highlight/true#M769054).